# how to draw a simple dendrogram using python?

Tags: python, python-3.7, dendrogram

I want to draw a dendrogram without using python libraries, so I want to implement a native program to do that with a small dataset. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

there's a built-in library that called turtle-graphics it's like using the math library or the built-in functions so it's from scratch.

The docs

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle